# How to apply column names to a pandas Series created via DataFrame.value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, d3py

I have the following pandas `Series` (which is actually the output of running `value_counts()` on a certain column - "Tipo de vivienda" - of a `DataFrame`:

[image]

With visualizaion libraries such as Seaborn, Bokeh etc. I can form a bar chart directly on this Series, without additional wrangling or conversion. Yet for [d3py](https://github.com/mikedewar/d3py), bar charts can only be generated from DataFrames (I believe). So I convert the series to a `DataFrame`:

[image]

I then set about plotting the bar chart:

```
p = d3py.PandasFigure(v_as_df)
```

At this point, I need to tell d3py that I want a Bar chart. I also need to tell it the titles of the columns, and this is where things fall down. Calling `v_as_df.columns()` gives me:

```
Index([u'Tipo de vivienda'], dtype='object')
```

Somewhat guessing what the columns names are, I try:

```
p += d3py.Bar('', 'Tipo de vivienda') # x, y
```

... but nothing gets displayed when I call `p.show()`, and I am guessing it's because I don't have a true `DataFrame`, but rather a `Series` casted as such.

Is calling `DataFrame()` on the `Series` the wrong way to go?

- Python: 2.7.11
- pandas: 0.18.0

Answer (score 1):

I don't think casting the Series as a DataFrame creates any problem.

However this looks wrong

```
p += d3py.Bar('', 'Tipo de vivienda') # x, y
```

The empty string is probably the source of the error.

Your DataFrame is composed of one index ('casa'), and one column ('Tipo de vivienda')

You're passing for you `x` argument an empty string, so d3py looks for a column that name is '',doesnt find it, and fails.

Solutions :
1. Check the doc of d3py and find how to pass an index as a value for the chart
2. Do the following :

```
v_as_df = v_as_df.reset_index()  # Transform your index into a column
print v_as_df.columns
### WILL output something like :**['index', 'Tipo de vivienda']**

then :
p = d3py.PandasFigure(v_as_df)
# adapt *'index'* with whatever you get from printing v_as_df.columns above
p += d3py.Bar('index', 'Tipo de vivienda')
```

Comment: Your suggested approach doesn't actually result in the plot being shown, but I can see your logic. Thanks.